# ESP32 driven MOSFET caused LED strip flickering

Tags: mosfet, led, esp32

I am currently trying to drive a small LED strip (60mA consumption) via 3AA batteries and an ESP32 with the circuit below.
My problem is, that no matter what settings I use on the software side, the LED strip will always be flickering. Interestingly, as soon as I directly connect the LED strip to the 3.3V (without resistor before the LED strip) of the LDO, the flickering is gone but as you might imagine, the LED are also way too dim.
Does anyone have an idea what may cause the flickering in the circuit below?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Why are you using p-channel mosfet as low side switch? Use n-channel one.

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's the only one I found in a hurry. Do you think this is the main problem?

Comment: no doubt that Vbat-Vcc is causing false triggering. Try >=10uF across that but most likely not bigly enough until you find an NPN or Nch

Comment: ok, I've found an NPN, put this into the circuit instead of the Pch and inverted the logic in software but still, the flickering remains. I've also tried to double the capacitance between VCC and GND but still the same.

Comment: It could problem on the software side, or you draw too much current which causes brown out and rebooting. Time to use oscilloscope.

Comment: what if you connect the gate/base to 3.3v?

Comment: Thanks to all of you - it seems that the LEDs cause a brown out!